# Writing data in TerraSAR-X COSAR Format

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, sentinel-snap, synthetic-aperture-radar

I am looking for a way to make SNAP read TS-X data that I have modified in some ways.

I have written Python code to read a TS-X stripmap product (from a *.cos file) and to perform some modifications on it. Now I would like to save the modified data back to a *.cos file (i.e., in COSAR format) so that I can treat the modified product just like any other TS-X product; I want to process it using SNAP.

Unfortunately, the [GDAL COSAR driver](https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/cosar.html) only supports reading, but not writing. Hence, I tried to save the data as GeoTIFF because the corresponding GDAL driver is much more versatile. Alas, I can't get SNAP to read the modified data if it's saved as GTIFF. I suppose that's because SNAP expects a certain structure for TS-X products.

Thus, I see two possible paths for my problem:

1. Find a way to write SAR-data in COSAR format (ideally in Python).

**Perhaps there is some alternative to GDAL which I just haven't found yet?**

I also checked the [TS-X L1b product specifications](https://www.intelligence-airbusds.com/files/pmedia/public/r460_9_030201_level-1b-product-format-specification_1.3.pdf) to check the COSAR file structure. I guess I could write my own code to try to emulate the file structure, but that looks like a rabbit hole I really don't want to go down.

**Surely there must be some library containing a suitable driver?**

2. Find a way to make SNAP read TS-X products when complex data is saved as GeoTIFF (or some other format  for which the GDAL driver supports writing).

Does anyone know what I can do to tell SNAP that the GTIFF I'm feeding it contains an SSC product?

I think when SNAP sees a GTIFF in a TS-X product it automatically expects MGD data.

Does anyone have any clue for either of the strategies?

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.

Comment: What kind of modifications did you undertake? On the image or metadata? Maybe there is a way to store i and q as ENVI raster and use them as parts of the SNAP internal BEAM DIMAP format. You can import TSX into SNAP and directly save it as BEAM DIMAP to see its file structure, and then replace the img raster files (or maybe even directly modify them with your python scripts).

Comment: I am modifying the data itself and leave the metadata untouched. I think BEAM-DIMAP is the way to go.

I like your idea of first converting the product to BEAM-DIMAP and then replacing the .img files. I'm working on stacks of more than 20 images, so I'd have to automate the conversion somehow. There is snappy, of course, but I have had bad experiences with it due to memory issues. Do you know of alternatives to snappy, ideally in python?

Comment: yes, there is snapista, which is python-based and easy to configure, but it calls the GPT in a convenient and efficient way: https://snap-contrib.github.io/snapista/

Comment: Awesome, I will give snapista  a try. Thanks!